# What happens when you use a continuous power in an array and then switch to a different power?

Tags: mutants-and-masterminds, mutants-and-masterminds-2e

This question is for Mutants & Masterminds 2nd edition, and it came up when I was thinking of a particular build.  Say I have a Continuous Create Object in an array, I create some objects and then switch to a different power in the array.  What happens to the objects?  Do they disappear, or do they remain until dismissed?  Does this answer change if I have Permanent Create Object instead, or Continuous Create Object with the Innate feat?  This question also applies to a Continuous Transform power as well, or a Continuous Minions power.  Does the transform continue to be applied, and do the minions continue to remain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Switching your array from a **Continuous** power means that you stop maintaining it. If it is a **Lasting** effect, then it moves to the appropriate sequence of saves. **Create Objects** [is a specific exception to the rule](http://atomicthinktank.com/viewtopic.php?p=315791#p315791). You can maintain those objects as a **Free action** because... well... mainly because it fits the kind of character that manifests such objects. When the Green Lantern makes a giant green statue, it doesn't go away when he makes a big boxing glove and punches someone with it. Another exception are **Independent** powers which are assumed to continue whether you will them or no until they fade away. **Innate** does not affect this. **Permanent** only applies for **Create Objects** off of the top of my head (all other powers are **Personal** range or can't be made **Permanent** such as the attack powers).

**Transform** and **Summon** go out of control upon switching array slots. **Transform** is a **Lasting** power, so the subjects will start making saves (although objects will always fail Fortitude saves from an **Affects Objects** power, so it's practically permanent) according to the normal duration of the power. **Summon**, [the minions go *poof* immediately upon switching](http://atomicthinktank.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=20742&p=330802#p330802). A generous GM might let you use **Independent** or [maintain them](http://atomicthinktank.com/viewtopic.php?f=18&t=29134&p=491513#p491513) if you have **Continuous**, but that's rare. Otherwise, look at dynamic arrays to keep points allocated to your **Summon**.

As regards **Lasting** powers, the following is stated in the FAQ:

> **If I use a power like Dazzle or Snare on somebody and then switch it to an Alternate Power, does the Dazzle or Snare effect go away?**
>
> No. The effects of instant powers remain, since you don’t have to be “using” the power to maintain them. The same is also true of lasting powers, so long as you meet the requirements of the power’s duration. A power like Create Object, on the other hand, which has a sustained duration, will stop working if you switch to an Alternate Power. If your Create Object power is continuous, the objects will last, since they “remain until they are destroyed, nullified, or you choose to dismiss them” per the power description.

I looked back over the sequence of "Lasting Results" in *Ultimate Power* and realized that I erred in stating that a **Continuous power** starts getting new saves. A **Lasting** **Continuous** power offers no new saves outside of **Extra Effort** or the "reasonable way to reverse a continuous lasting effect other than countering or nullifying it, such as a medical treatment, folk remedy, other powers, or the like" (p. 17). I would personally not let **Continuous** work *ad infinitum* after switching array slots, but that would fall under house rules and GM purview under Rule 0.